# Show a div when a variable is set and let it disappear after x seconds

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page with a variable that is set true or false on pageload. I want to show a specific div when the variable is true and then the div disappears after x seconds. When its false the div stays hidden.

My code shows the div but it doesn't disappear after x seconds.

```
    if($showNotification == TRUE){
        echo "<div class='notification'>notification!!</div>";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).load(
                    function() {
                       $("div.notification").fadeIn();
                       setTimeout(function() {
                          $("div.notification").fadeOut("slow");
                       }, 3000); 
                  });  
              </script>';

     }
```

Comment: What is in your CSS? Do you use dispay:none or visibility:hidden?

Comment: does the div really fades in or is it displayed on page load?

Comment: I have no css, I dont use display:none or something. 
It doesn't fade in. It is just displayed when $showNotificiation is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your JS with this:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.notification').hide().fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nEsg9/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
$(document).load( ...
```

use

```
$(document).ready( ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($showNotification == TRUE){
    echo "<div class='notification' style='display:none'>notification!!</div>";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).load(
                function() {
                   $("div.notification").fadeIn();
                   setTimeout(function() {
                      $("div.notification").fadeOut("slow");
                   }, 3000); 
              });  
          </script>';

 }
```

It shows because it is not hidden before you do the fadein. So fadein has no effect (it is already there).

Answer (score 1):

Use ready instead of load.

Here is a working example, but without fade in, cause it's always displayed

http://jsfiddle.net/2JKxr/1/

```
$(document).ready(
            function() {
               $("div.notification").fadeIn();
               setTimeout(function() {
                  $("div.notification").fadeOut("slow");
               }, 3000); 
          });
```